# Add displayName or ApplicationID URI as a Client Credentials claim

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have (what I hope) is a fairly straight forward question:

I'm using the AzureAD (brand new to it) Client Credentials flow.  I want to add the (displayName or ApplicationID URI) as a claim in the access_token as I want the human readable client_id for logging.

---

This started because the subject (sub) is the uuid of the client and is immutable (best I can tell). Sure, no worries, so instead I just want to add another claim to the access_token of the displayName or the Application ID URI of the client.  I want to use this for logging purposes. I have clicked through most of the AzureAD docs, stackoverflow, google, etc, but it appears my question is too specific so I can't find it.

I looked through the optional claims, but these seem focused on the user's info (I have no users, this is all service to service).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims

Am I overlooking something obvious here?

Thanks!

---

Here is the claims in the token, I have redacted the claims as much as possible.

- POST: https://login.windows.net/00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000/oauth2/v2.0/token
- Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Body: client_id, client_secret, scope

```
{
  "header": {
    "alg": "RS256",
    "kid": "nOo3ZDrODXEK1jKWhXslHR_KXEg",
    "typ": "JWT",
    "x5t": "nOo3ZDrODXEK1jKWhXslHR_KXEg"
  },
  "payload": {
    "aud": "test-audience",
    "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000/",
    "iat": 1614866520,
    "nbf": 1614866520,
    "exp": 1614870420,
    "aio": "<snip>",
    "appid": "6644659a-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
    "appidacr": "1",
    "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000/",
    "oid": "<snip>",
    "rh": "0.AAAA<snip>",
    "roles": [
      "test-role",
    ],
    "sub": "01b32d39-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
    "tid": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
    "uti": "<snip>",
    "ver": "1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

displayName claim is included in the access token by default.

It is `app_displayname`. And there is another claim named `appid` which means the client_id of the app registration in the access token by default.

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims) has shown the `appid` claim.

Although it doesn't mention `app_displayname` claim, you can decode your access token in https://jwt.io to find it.

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  I'm not seeing that.  but I do see that I have a v1.0 token being returned.

Comment: @CadeThacker Can you provide a screenshot of your decoded token from https://jwt.io?

Comment: I could not put it in the comment so I edited my question and put it up there. Huge thank you.  I feel like this should be easy, but I just can't find the secret switch to enable it :D

Comment: @CadeThacker `00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is the app id of AAD Graph. It should not be a tenant id. Please use a real tenant id. And may I know what is the value of `scope`? Besides, try to use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/token` instead of `https://login.windows.net/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Comment: sorry for the confusion, that was my attempt at redacting information.  Let me clean up and update the original question with the iterations and will post again tomorrow. Thanks again for all you assistance.  Always good to learn!

Comment: Ok, so i'm now deep in learning about Azure AD v1 and Microsoft Identity Platform (aka Aure AD v2). I learned about: `requestedAccessTokenVersion: 2` set.  This still did not fix the issue, but was good learning. On an interesting note it changed my audience value to a UUID ugh. Anyway, last point, some else asked this exact question and did not get an answer:  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/50421 I'm going to leave this for now, and talk with our Azure AD Admin this week and then circle back once I learn more. Thanks again.

Comment: @CadeThacker So you are calling your own web API rather that Microsoft Graph right? Looking forward to your reply at your earliest convenience.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response.  Correct.  I'm calling my own API and not the MS Graph API.

Comment: @CadeThacker If so, you should look into the `azp` cliam (only in v2.0 token), which means the app id of the app registration.

Comment: Wanted to close the loop on this.  What I'm asking appears to not be possible.  Oh well.  Thanks for all your help @allenwu I'm super grateful.   Here is the official response. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/50421#issuecomment-810380735